# On the Yale sparse matrix format

Tags: calculus, matrices, terminology, computer-science

I am wondering if someone could provide me with additional information with regard to the so called Yale sparse matrix format, other that what can be already found here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

In particular, which specific programms make use of it? Which (research or practical) goals does it achieve as compared with other options? Can it be considered a standard way to make a sparse matrix out of a dense one?

Thnaks in advance.

Comment: Scikit.sparse is a popular library for sparse matrix operations in python. It supports several sparse matrix formats, and I think it tends to favor the CSC format, which I think is related to the Yale format. You might also like to read the Matlab documentation about sparse matrices to see what format(s) Matlab uses.

Comment: Actually, the Matlab documentation doesn't make it obvious which sparse matrix format is used. Perhaps because most users don't need to know which format is used to store sparse matrices and which algorithms are used to perform sparse matrix operations efficiently.

Comment: @littleO Well, rather than knowing which programms make use of that format, I am interested in knowing more about the way in which that Yale format works, from a technical and mathematical perspective.

Comment: @littleO Actually, [documentation](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) says "MATLAB stores sparse matrices in compressed sparse column format." As far as I know, the sparse toolbox is/was based on SparseSuite by Tim Davis, which uses the column-wise storage as well. This is also somewhat consistent with the storage format for dense matrices which are stored by columns as well.

Comment: Related to the original question, the Yale format is more or less identical to the CSR format (it is even written on the linked wiki page), so it is used anywhere where the CSR format is, that is, in most sparse matrix codes.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Once the sparse matrix is created, is it possible to unambiguously retrieve all the information back so as to land in the original dense matrix? If so, how?

Comment: The Yale (and CSR) format is clearly described in the three items following "The Yale sparse matrix format stores an initial sparse..." For each nonzero entry, you can identify from this data structure its row and column indices, hence you can identify the nonzero entries of the whole matrix. Otherwise, I do not understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Yale Sparse Matrix Package](https://cpsc.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/tr112.pdf) research report referred to in the Wikipedia article, the example matrix and its corresponding storage format was given as
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 9
\end{bmatrix}
\\{}
\\
\begin{array}{c|cc}
   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13\\
\hline
IA & 1 & 4 & 5 & 8 & 12 & 13\\
JA & 1 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 4 & 5\\
A  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 5 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 8 & 9
\end{array}
$$
This is exactly what we know today as compressed sparse row (CSR) format, although because the above matrix is symmetric, it can also be read as compressed sparse column (CSC). The report further mentions about representing the symmetric matrix using only the upper triangle, making it obvious that the format was actually CSR.

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
\hline
IA & 1 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 9 & 10\\
JA & 1 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 5\\
A  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9
\end{array}
$$

For the nonsymmetric matrix, this format requires you to store one index per non-zero, and one index per row + an additional index, compared to Coordinate list (COO) format which requires two indices (row-column pair) per non-zero. Also, it is easier to do performant arithmetic operations with CSR compared to COO, which is why it is usually considered to be the Starter Pack for users of sparse matrices (subjective opinion).

To store the values in CSR, we lay out all the non-zeroes into the array $A$, put their corresponding column numbers to $JA$, then put the index of where the beginning of each row starts in the array into $IA$. If there are no values for that row, put the index of the next row that contains a value. Finally, append the number of non-zeroes plus one to the end of array $IA$ (if the indexing starts from zero, then append number of non-zeroes instead).

To retrieve a value, you get lookup the index of its row, then scan along the value together with the column index array starting from this index until you find the correct column, or until you reach the end of that row, in which case the value is zero.

As for the new Yale format, I am not able to find an online accessible resource, but the [Sparse Matrix Multiplication Package](https://netlib.org/aicm/smmp) makes a reference to it and gives a summary on how it is stored. It seems to be specifically for square matrix, and separates it to the diagonal, lower triangle, and upper triangle matrices, storing it in that order.